# Challenging MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a blogging app that requires a unique query.

**Problem**: I need to display **one** parent post, all it's children posts (**up to a certain number before requiring pagination**), and up to 5 comments associated with each child post, and the parent.

I wrote this query, but it doesn't work because it will return only 5 comments that belong to the parent post.

```
SELECT
    posts.id, posts.postTypeId, posts.parentId, posts.ownerUserId, posts.body
, users.id AS authorId, users.displayname AS authorDisplayName
, comments.id AS commentId, comments.text AS commentText
, comments.commentOwnerUserId, comments.commentOwnerDisplayName
FROM posts
JOIN users ON posts.owneruserid = users.id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT comments.id, comments.postId, comments.text, commenters.id AS commentOwnerUserId, commenters.displayname AS commentOwnerDisplayName
        FROM comments
        JOIN users AS commenters ON comments.userid = commenters.id
        ORDER BY comments.createdat ASC
        LIMIT 0,5 ) AS comments ON comments.postid = posts.id
WHERE posts.id = @postId OR posts.parentId = @postId
ORDER BY posts.posttypeid, posts.createdAt
```

The query returns the parent post, all it's children, and the first 5 comments it encounters, (usually they belong to the parent because we are ordering by postTypeId, and the parent is the first post). If the first post doesn't have 5 comments, it moves on the next post and returns those comments, until the 5 limit is reached.

**What I need is to return one parent post and all it's children posts, and up to 5 comments for each child, the parent. I also need the owner data for each post and comment.**

**UPDATE** I'm open to doing this with more than one query if it will scale well. The only condition is that the parent and children posts retrieval happens in the same query.

Any idea how I can write such a query? I included my schema below.

```
/* Posts table */
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `posttypeid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `parentid` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `createdat` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `parentId` (`parentid`)
KEY `userId` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=572 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

/* Comments table */
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `postid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `createdat` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `postId` (`postid`),
  KEY `userId` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

/* users table */
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `displayname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `createdat` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=66 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: why do you need this to do in one query ?

Comment: @Rufinus, if there's an easier way with more queries, sure. I just can't visualize/think of a way to ask post comments after getting the posts. That's would required a crazy `WHERE` clause for the comments query, no? `WHERE postId = @postId1 OR postId = @postId 2` etc... In fact if I could avoid teh sub select, it would be even better.

Comment: query parents; loop over parent; select posts; loop over posts; select comments; loop over comments. This are just 3 nested loops. which language are you using ?

Comment: @Rufinus, using ColdFusion. It is easy for me loop over the queries, but that would mean 11 queries for a 10 post scenario! I dont think I can afford that.

Comment: @Mohamad: these are only PK or FK queries, thei're fast. Your query above queries 5 tables at once... what will be faster :-)

Comment: @Rufinus, that is one solution, I guess. I do not need to query the parents. I need one parent and its children, which can be done in the same query. Then I can loop over those and get the comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take as granted that every child has exactly one parent. Then, I think this will work:

```
SELECT p.*             <-- post details
     , u.*             <-- user details
     , cc.*            <-- comment details
FROM 
  ( ( SELECT parentid AS id
      FROM posts
      WHERE posts.id = @mypostid     <-- the id of the post we want 
    )
    UNION ALL
    ( SELECT child.id
      FROM posts AS parent
        JOIN posts AS child
          ON child.parentid = parent.id
      WHERE parent.id = 
            ( SELECT posts.parentid
              FROM posts
              WHERE posts.id = @mypostid)   <-- the id of the post we want 
      ORDER BY child.createdat            <-- any order you prefer
      LIMIT x, 5                          <-- 5 children posts
    )
  ) AS pp
  JOIN posts p
    ON p.id = pp.id
  JOIN users
    ON users.id = p.userid
  JOIN comments cc
    ON cc.postid = pp.id
WHERE cc.postid IN
  ( SELECT c.id
    FROM comments c
    WHERE c.postid = pp.id
    ORDER BY c.createdat             <-- any order you prefer
    LIMIT y, 5                       <-- 5 comments for every post
  )
```

The `x,5` should be replaced with `0,5` for first five childen posts and `y,5` with `0,5` for first five comments. Then with `5,5` for next five, `10,5` for next five, etc.

---

**UPDATE**

Sorry, my mistake. The above gives the error:

```
This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

I'll wrap my head up to work around this :)

Comment: thank you. I just give it a twirl, and I got unknown comlumn "mypost.parentid" error. I changed that to posts.parentId, then got another unknown column error "pp.id" :/

Comment: also, does this select the children first, then the parent? I'm trying to wrap my head around it, and it's proving too much this early in the morning :D

Comment: Yes, the second error is not trivial. I'll check first and then edit my answer.

Comment: @Mohamad: It first selects the parent id and its children ids, in the subquery with the `UNION`. Then it relates those ids with other tables.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking to store hierarchical data.  This isn't so much a hard question as it is a bit of a time-consuming one.  I would suggest reading a really good article from a few years ago named [*Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL*](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) by Mike Hillyer.  It's got some really good conceptual suggestions as well as example implementations of the kind of system it sounds like you're designing.  Definitely read the "Find the Immediate Subordinates of a Node" section.  :)

Comment: I do not think this is a hierarchical issue. I do not have any nesting that is more than 1 level: Parent and Child. Both have comments.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you will have paging of some sort to restrict the amount of top level posts.

You would also need some summary information on the number of comments, childposts in the posts table or a post summary table.

The comments table would need sequence column by post

1: Get all parent posts, (parentId = 0) & construct an IN clause of postids

2: Get all children posts by passing the postids obtained in 1, order by postid which will help in segregation. Add these posts to the overall IN clause
   Get comments by passing the postids from 1 & 2.
   Restrict the number of comments by using the number of comments & the sequence column 
   For ex:  join comments & post_summary where post_comment_seq between (noofcommentsforthepost - 5) and noofcommentsforthepost

You can look at in clause performance here [Performance of MYSQL "IN"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537675/performance-of-mysql-in)

Comment: I actually need only one parent. But yes, if the number of children posts is high, I would want to paginate. The comment number is denormalized.

Answer (score 2):

I've adjusted the other query from [Your Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209725/using-a-limit-on-a-left-join-in-mysql/6209780#6209780) to simply include a WHERE clause on your ParentID.  That was the condition I didn't know you were looking for to limit return set.  I added where the post ID = the one you want OR the ParentID = the one you want.

By having the ORDER by the POST ID, it will naturally have the originating parent ID in the first position as others would be derived from it sequentially.  I think that will solve you again.

Comment: I saw it. Thank you very much. I'm going to run some tests on and see how it does. SQL has got to be the worst language to program in--for me at least!